# Implement a delegate that overrides an abstract method in C#

Tags: .net, inheritance, c#-4.0, delegates, abstract-class

I am fairly new to .Net, and I am clearly doing something wrong here. In my base abstract class, I have the following delegate:

```
public delegate bool DEnqueue(ref IPCPriorityMessage item, byte priority);
```

... and the following method declaration:

```
public abstract DEnqueue Enqueue();
```

In my instance class, I have the following:

```
public override DEnqueue Enqueue;
```

I point Enqueue to the applicable local method. I can only get this to work if I don't use inheritance or don't use delegates.

My exact objectives are:

1. Use the base abstract class to force the design pattern. Instances must contain a method Engueue().
2. Use delegates in the instance class so that the applicable private enqueue() method is called when the public Enqueue() method is called.

How do I do this? I tried using interfaces, but has basically the same problem.

NOTE: I only know at runtime which private enqueue() to use, hence my use of delegates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're looking for the [Template Method Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern). No need to use delegates.

Comment: Everything else is template. But without using a delegate, I'd have to make a double-call, i.e. one to public instance method+ 1 to internal method via delegate (or if statement).

Comment: Yes. Is that bad? Note that the second call happens within your first method, so it's transparent to the caller.

Comment: Not bad... just a little overhead I'd rather not have. Is what I am trying to do not possible?

Comment: I don't fully understand what you're trying to achieve. It seems you want to _replace_ a method with a delegate, which is not possible. Is my understanding right? You can always call a delegate from within a method though.

Comment: I have two possible private methods that I want to map one public method to. Depending on the initialization of the object, one of the internal classes is assigned to the public class.

Comment: @IanC: and you don't think delegates will add overhead?  The double call will likely be inlined away anyway.  And have you measured to see if it's really a performance bottleneck?  Otherwise, this is just premature optimization gone horribly wrong.

Comment: @IanC: Delegates shouldn't be used like this. They're more like a callback mechanism. What you want is "simple" class design.

Answer (score 1):

First, the method declaration in your base class probably doesn't say what you think. What it says is that the `Enqueue` method *returns a delegate of type `DEnqueue`*, not that the method has the same type as the delegate.

What you could do is to have a property of type `DEnqueue` in your base class:

```
public abstract DEnqueue Enqueue { get; }
```

You can (or actually, have to) then implement it using a delegate:

```
private DEnqueue m_enqueue;

public override DEnqueue Enqueue
{
    get { return m_enqueue; }
}
```

You can call the delegate in the property the same way as you would call a method.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know if this pattern would be faster than using non-delegates in a typical template method pattern? (as per the other answer)

Comment: @IanC, asking about performance like this smells of premature optimization. Just use what's better design for your case (which is likely to be the template method pattern). But if you really have to know: calling a delegate is slower than calling normal method, so using delegates is going to be (probably unmeasurably) slower. On the other hand, if the condition to choose the correct method was slow, using delegates might be faster.